# two way binding [(ngmodel)] unaffected by jquery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular7

**I need to update the angular model on a js change event, 
this is a simplified, isolated demo:**

hero-form.component.html:

```
<button type="button" id='btn1'>change</button>
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" [(ngModel)]="str1" />{{str1}}
```

hero-form.component.ts:

```
...
    import * as $ from "jquery";
...
export class HeroFormComponent implements OnInit {
    str1 = "initval";

    ngAfterViewInit(){
    var txt1 = $('#txt1');

    $('#btn1').on('click', function(){  
      txt1.val('new val').change();
      // when js/jquery triggers a change on the input, I need the str1 
      // which was bound using [(ngModel)] to be updated
    });
}
```

when clicking the button the value of the textbox changes to `new val` but the interpolation  `{{str1}}` is not affected, however if I change the value of the textbox manually it works.

is it possible to update the model bound with ngmodel on a js change event ?

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in stackblitz.it will be really helpfull for StackOverflow community to help in a better way.

Comment: To me, the biggest question is "why"? Why use jQuery at all here? Why fight the framework? Why not just do it the Angular way?

Comment: I would suggest to use the angular way of binding events instead of trying to combine it with JQuery so it will work out of the box.

Comment: you should use `txt1.val('new val').trigger("input")`

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek to use a jquery component in angular

Comment: @ShridharSharma that makes no difference

Comment: @Shilly I need to use a big js component that triggers change event, I isolated the code in my question to make it easier to understand the problem

Comment: @Omu The problem is that JQuery has no sensible idea of teaching decent MVC structure. ( One of my biggest problems with jquery. ) So my best advice would be to use the angular way of binding events, using `(click)=""` and then writing the actual trigger event of the JQuery component inside that event so you can try to manually sync the jquery component and the angular state. But you have to hook up basically All the events the JQuery module exposes, so usually I prefer to just rewrite the entire JQuery-based component in angular as it's less error-prone.

Comment: @Shilly all I need is to have a js change event to trigger a model change the same way a user typing in the textbox triggers the model change

Comment: @Omu, that's what you already tried no? Just triggering the change event with `txt1.val('new val').change();` didn't work, since angular does not update model on manual change triggers. Hence I suggest using the angular (click) to write the same event so that the angular model updates first. Then you can do any other bookkeeping you need inside that handler as well and change the state of the jquery component. That sounds alot more workable than the other way around. But if it has to be the other way around, enjoy implementing https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef .

Answer (score 1):

In angular project we should not implement your requirement like your way.

You can use `(click)` event and `#txt1` to get value

In ts component implement change str1 value.

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Binding data in Angular';

  str1 = "initval";

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }
  change(val) {
    console.log(val)
    this.str1 = val;
  }
}
```

Updated HTML

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<button type="button" id='btn1' (click)="change(txt1.value)">change</button>
<input type="text" #txt1 id="txt1" name="txt1" />{{str1}}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-click-change-value

Comment: I need to trigger a model change on a js/jquery change event, the button is not important it is there just to create an isolated demo

Comment: when you develop angular project, you should change mind when you use jquery

Comment: I know all this, atm I need to use a big js/jquery component in angular and the change event that it triggers doesn't affect the model